# How do I change my .minecraft folder location in the old launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I know that there's a way to change the minecraft folder location in the newer launchers, but how do I do it in 1.5.2? I've tried to move the roaming folder and searched online, but none of the methods I tried worked and few were about the older launchers.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use the old launcher? I'm fairly certain with the current launcher you're able to use those old versions.

Comment: My computer is not able to use the new launcher for some reason- I've tried a lot to fix it but it doesn't work. So I use the old launcher.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use symbolic links:

[image]

If you would like to fully move home (not just the game), you can start the Minecraft launcher with the `--workDir` argument.

Answer (score -1):

I don't remember the name of the program but I can check if needed. What you want to do is put your Minecraft folder where you want it then create a symbolic link in the usual place. Minecraft will look in the usual place and follow the link to the new location like a shortcut. This effectively changes the location.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a symbolic link? Do I create a shortcut?

Comment: @Hacker you'll need either a special program to create them or a command prompt command to create them. I'll try to find the name of it for you